# JupyterHub Deployment behind Apache Reverse Proxy add https

Tags: apache, jupyterhub

I am deploying a jupyterhub instance running in docker running behind an apache reverse proxy.

The jupyter hub login page works well with the following apache configuration

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
   
  <Location /jupyter>
    ProxyPass "http://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter"
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"
  </Location>
     
  <LocationMatch "/jupyter/(user/[^/]*)/(api/kernels/[^/]+/channels|terminals/websocket)(.*)">
    ProxyPassMatch ws://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter/$1/$2$3
    ProxyPassReverse ws://jupyterhub:8000/jupyter/$1/$2$3
  </LocationMatch>
```

After the login succeeds I then click the start server which kicks off the SinglUserLabApp with a mixture of 200s and 400s.

For example, I get the following 200s on the static resources

```
/jupyter/user/mtwells/static/lab/...
```

but 401 Unauthorized on everything else

```
/jupyter/user/mtwells/api/lab
```

My guess is my LocationMatch regex is not quite right, but I am unable to find a clear example of all the routes.